# Проверка заполнения формы с использованием JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Не получается сделать проверку заполнения полей для формы (если не заполнено, нужно выводить подсказку для пользователя, какое поле нужно заполнить).

```html
<link media="all" href="form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="formscroll">

<div id="form" style="width: 550px; height: 570px; margin-top:-100px; scrolling=no; margin:0 auto; box-sizing: border-box;">
<div class="inner-form" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<font size="4" color="#ffffff"><b>Заголовок формы</b></font>
<center><img src="order_tube.png" width="250px"></center>
<h4>текст</h4>
<div id="successText"  style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<h4>Спасибо! Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время!</h4>
</div>
<div class="landFormRow"  style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<form class="form" action="http://yandex.ru" method="post" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<input class="my-input" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" value="" type="text">
<input class="my-input" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="+7(___)___-__-__" type="tel">
<a class="button order-btn my-a-button" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();return false;"  style="box-sizing: border-box;">Отправить</a>
<h4>текст</h4>
</form>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Пробовал required - не помогает.
Как понял, required работает если отправлять форму традиционным способом (input type="submit"). В моём случае нужно делать проверку на javascript.

Нашел такой вариант проверки:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var fields = {
  name: false,
  phone: false
};
var f = function(){
  switch (this.id) {
    case 'name':
      fields[this.id] = this.value.match(/[\s\w]+/) ? true : false;
      break;
    case 'phone':
      fields[this.id] = this.value.match(/[\d]+/) ? true : false;
      break;
  }
  var sum = 0;
  for (var key in fields) {
    sum += fields[key] ? 1 : 0;
  }
  sum === 3 && alert('message')
};
$(function(){
 $('#name').change(f);
 $('#phone').change(f);
})

</script>
```

Но не работает... 
Прошу помощи у сообщества, самостоятельно найти ошибку не хватает знаний.

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/